# Connecting android program to the database

Tags: android

I created an android application on eclipse which works perfectly on emulator. It stores data in the mysql db. Works perfectly. Now I need to demonstrate it in my phone. I installed it in my phone and connected it to laptop by WiFi. But it didn't connect with my db. Is there any way to connect it to the db in laptop?. I changed local host to ipv4 of laptop but it doesn't work. Help on this please

Comment: Is your laptop's firewall set to allow access to the database from the phone?

Comment: show us your connection code...

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Wifi Hotspot of your android phone and connect your Laptop with your phone.

Start your server at localhost

Now open command prompt and enter ipconfig command you will get following things

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::80bc:e378:19ab:e448%11
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.76
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

Copy this 192.168.43.76 and put it in your code as the URL instead of 127.0.0.1 or localhost which you are using to access your server. Please set you network as "Home Network" and turn off the Firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked perfectly when I use the port number with IP address